# Finding a task completed animation library to use in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, animation

I want to find a task  completed animation like the one below which I can use in my Android app.  when I press a button I want this to pop up, simple.

my current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/location" />

    <cdflynn.android.library.checkview.CheckView
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:checkView_strokeColor="@color/green"
        app:checkView_strokeWidth="1dp"/>
</fragment>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://github.com/cdflynn/checkview

Instructions to use it are all on there too:

```
<cdflynn.android.library.checkview.CheckView
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:checkView_strokeColor="@color/green"
        app:checkView_strokeWidth="@dimen/check_stroke_width"/>
```

Call check():

```
 mCheckView.check();
```

Add jitpack to your root build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Add as a dependency

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.cdflynn:checkview:v1.1'
    }
```

All credit to the GitHub User Collin Flynn, cdflynn.

Comment: in my google maps activity, I call `CheckView mCheckView = (CheckView) this.findViewById(R.id.check);
        mCheckView.check();
` but the result is weird: see here: https://imgur.com/a/Yco7RZn . there's no animation too. how can I fix it?

Comment: I would have to look at the whole XML Code.  Looks like a layout issue. Lets do a direct chat?

Comment: Okay, once this problem is fixed, I will award you

Comment: How can we direct chat on here?

Comment: we can communicate here. I uploaded my xml code check it out

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I will need to experiment with it.  The goal is to put the check mark in the center right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196260/discussion-between-treewallie-and-user11315386).

Comment: You're not responding in chat.  It works fine in my end.  The official Github Project that I downloaded (Sample) works fine too.  

Last thing I can think of is changing  to 10dp width
` app:checkView_strokeWidth="10dp"`

Also adding a RelativeLayout within your Fragment if it is not showing.

Comment: It actually doesn't work within a Fragment (the animation part).  You need to put it outside of a Fragment to see the animation.

Comment: I'll award you, and we'll solve this at a later time. It says I can award you in 19 hours.

Comment: Try the CheckView first without it inside a Fragment so you can see how it works.

Comment: I'll check this out in a few days because I'm currently busy, thanks! By the way, I can't award a bounty because the question has been put on hold. However, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: You would need to reword the subject question to not have the word "library" for the hold to be removed.